# tabhost inside actionbar using fragment

Tags: java, android

I have used actionbar and it is working fine. I have four fragment in the actionbar. I want to implement tabhost in one of the fragment. I have used the following code.

```
    package com.main.udebate;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Info extends Fragment {
    public Info() {
    }

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    private TabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Intent i = new Intent(Info.this, about.class);

         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info, container, false);
         mTabHost = (TabHost) view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
         mTabHost.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec tab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("my tab content");
        tab.setIndicator("my tab content");
        tab.setContent(i);
        mTabHost.addTab(tab);
        mTabHost = (TabHost) view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        return view;

    }
}
```

I am getting error on `Intent i = new Intent(Info.this, about.class);` line as The constructor Intent(Info, Class) is undefined.

About.java

```
  package com.main.udebate;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class about extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
    }
}
```

Can someone pls help me to set tabhost inside fragment.

Thanks,

Comment: check this ---> http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/

Answer (score 1):

try to use this

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), about.class);
```

instead of this line

```
Intent i = new Intent(Info.this, about.class);
```

As Info.this does not mean any context thats why you get "The constructor Intent(Info, Class) is undefined." this error.

In fragment where you use `this` reference you should instead use `getActivity()` reference